# How get data-id in Bootstrap SelectPicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am beginner in JS. I have Bootstrap selectpicker. I have this code:

```html
<select class="form-control selectpicker select_subcription" name="subscription">
  <optgroup label="Przedłuż wybrane profile o:">
    <option class="selectValueFromPriceList" value="1" data-id="1.00">Przedłużam wybrane profile o 7 dni za 1.00 zł / konto</option>
    <option class="selectValueFromPriceList" value="3" data-id="2.00">Przedłużam wybrane profile o 30 dni za 2.00 zł / konto</option>
    <option class="selectValueFromPriceList" value="5" data-id="4.00">Przedłużam wybrane profile o 90 dni za 4.00 zł / konto</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Promuj wybrane ogłoszenia:">
    <option class="selectValueFromPriceList" value="6" data-id="11.00">Wypromuj na liście ogłoszeń przez 7 dni za 11.00 zł / konto</option>
    <option class="selectValueFromPriceList" value="8" data-id="22.00">Wypromuj na liście ogłoszeń przez 30 dni za 22.00 zł / konto</option>
    <option class="selectValueFromPriceList" value="9" data-id="33.00">Wypromuj na liście ogłoszeń przez 60 dni za 33.00 zł / konto</option>
    <option class="selectValueFromPriceList" value="10" data-id="44.00">Wypromuj na liście ogłoszeń przez 90 dni za 44.00 zł / konto</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

```js
$('.select_subcription').selectpicker({
  noneSelectedText: 'Wybierz płatności z listy'
});

$('.select_subcription').on('changed.bs.select', function(e) {
  //alert(e.target.value);
  var summary = 0;
  var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
  var price = e.target.value; // here i need data-id
  alert(price);
  summary = countCheckedCheckboxes * price;
  $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text(summary);
});
```

I need in:

```
var price = e.target.value;
```

Not data-id selected option - not value.

How can I change it? I want change

```
var price = e.target.value;
```

for

```
var price = e.target.data-id
```

but I don't know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following

```
var price = $(".select_subcription option:selected").attr('data-id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `e.target` would relate to the `select`, not the `option` which was chosen so even if the call to get the data worked it would return nothing. You need to first get the selected option.

From there you can either use jQuery's `data()` method to get the value or the native `dataset` property, something like this:

```js
$('.select_subcription').on('changed.bs.select', function(e) {
  var summary = 0;
  var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
  var price = $(this).find('option:selected').data('id');
  console.log(price);

  summary = countCheckedCheckboxes * price;
  $('#count-checked-checkboxes').text(summary);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 
$( ".select_subcription" ).change(function(e) {

  //other code snippet
  console.log(e.target.value);
  console.log($(".select_subcription option:selected").attr('data-id'));
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control selectpicker select_subcription" name="subscription">
  <optgroup label="Przedłuż wybrane profile o:">
    <option class="selectValueFromPriceList" value="1" data-id="1.00">Przedłużam wybrane profile o 7 dni za 1.00 zł / konto
    </option>
    <option class="selectValueFromPriceList" value="3" data-id="2.00">Przedłużam wybrane profile o 30 dni za 2.00 zł / konto
    </option>
    <option class="selectValueFromPriceList" value="5" data-id="4.00">Przedłużam wybrane profile o 90 dni za 4.00 zł / konto
    </option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Promuj wybrane ogłoszenia:">
    <option class="selectValueFromPriceList" value="6" data-id="11.00">Wypromuj na liście ogłoszeń przez 7 dni za 11.00 zł / konto
    </option>
    <option class="selectValueFromPriceList" value="8" data-id="22.00">Wypromuj na liście ogłoszeń przez 30 dni za 22.00 zł / konto
    </option>
    <option class="selectValueFromPriceList" value="9" data-id="33.00">Wypromuj na liście ogłoszeń przez 60 dni za 33.00 zł / konto
    </option>
    <option class="selectValueFromPriceList" value="10" data-id="44.00">Wypromuj na liście ogłoszeń przez 90 dni za 44.00 zł / konto
    </option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```